# Bash - Find and replace a line in a file in number of directories

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a file structure where I have 700 directories. All the directories have a file named `config.xml`. I have prefixed 25 directories with `1111-` name. Now, I want to replace a block of code in `config.xml` files from all those 25 directories. I want to have a loop (`for` or `while`) for that.

Comment: What have written so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search the file with `find`, `grep` the directory and replace the string using `sed`.

```
find . -iname 'config.xml' | grep '1111' | sed -i 's/STRINGTOREPLACE/NEWSTRING/'
```

Comment: What if the file config is found in a sub directory of one of those 1111 folders. grep would get that too and I don't think @Drew wants that.

Comment: hmm. in this case one might want to use the -depth parameter.

Comment: Maybe `ls 1111-*/config.xml` is simpler than `find...`

Comment: @Luca: Thats what exactly happend!!! I have config.xml files in the subfolders too.

Comment: @OhadBasan: I used the -maxdepth flag and it worked. However, after running the command it complains about not having input file to the sed command. Any help?

Comment: @Drew
yes. I had a mistake.
try this find -iname 'config.xml' -exec sed -i s/hello/bar/ {} \;

Comment: @OhadBasan Sorry for the late response. I have just marked the answer as a correct one.... :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
find . -name "1111-*" -type d -exec cd {} \; -exec /absolute.path/to/shell_script_modifying_config.xml \;
```

Comment: I am not using grep.  The find command I provided searches for directories starting with 1111-.  Then it cd's into those directories and runs the shell script. So it would not go into subdirectories of 1111- folders.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a recursive function:

```
folder_recursive() {
    for i in "$1"/*;do
        if [ -d "$i" ];then
            folder_recursive "$i"
        elif [ -f "$i" ]; then
            lastFolder = ${$1##*/}
            if [[ $lastFolder == *"1111-"* ]]; then
                if [[ $i == *"config.xml" ]]; then
                    #Replace block of code
                    file_path=$i
                    original=$(<file_path) # Read from file
                    to_replace="aaaabbbb"
                    replacer="xxxxyyyy"
                    result=${original/$to_replace/$replacer} #This will replace the first instance of to_replace
                    # If you want to replace all instances use:
                    # ${original//$to_replace/$replacer}
                    echo $result > $i #Overwrite file
                fi
            fi
        fi
    done
}

path= "root/of/folder/structure"
folder_recursive $path
```

Comment: How is this a recursive function?

Comment: @Luca: I am not sure how this is going to replace the code. Where I am going to tell this function to look for a specific line(s) of the code and then replace it with the new one!! Please hellp!

Comment: @Drew this code doesn't do the part you mentioned. It looks recursively into the folder structure and finds the files you want to edit. You didn't give details as to how to edit them so I inserted the comment #Replace block of code.

Comment: @luca: Let's say I have a string "aaaabbbb" in all the config.xml files and i want that to be replaced by "xxxxyyyy". Now how would you re-write that function. Sorry I am a newbie to this.

Comment: I'm editing the answer with sample code. Let me know if it works

Comment: @LucaAngioloni I am sorry but did not work, it might be me not understanding the code correctly or do not know how to run the function written above.